# report customization in Odoo v9

Tags: odoo

I've installed Odoo v9, and now I want to create and use some custom Invoice, PO and quote templates. I've looked around but can't find no such feature or any plugin. Does anyone knows how can I create custom Invoice templates in Odoo v9?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo V9, you have to **Activate the Developer Mode** to make changes in Technical features. You can Activate developer mode from Help menu in the Right top of the browser [Please click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1NBR.png).

Once Developer mode activated, you can see **Technical** Menu under **Settings** menu. In that you can see **Email -> Templates** menu. From **Template** menu you can create and use custom Invoice, PO and quote templates.

Comment: Hi Nilesh Sheliya, Exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how to thank you ! Have a great day

Comment: Now will have to find my way on the customize these templates ;) Thanks so much

Comment: Eh, Sorry for the spam, can anyone show me how to customize these templates? :(